# Adding weekday name to x-axis in a chart

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to add a weekday name to the horizontal axis in a chart (SSRS).

In horizontal Axis Properties I went to number, then Custom, and added:

```
=(WeekdayName(Fields!Date.Value))
```

It nearly works. I have put in this week's dates into the parameters (23/02/2015 - 28/02/2015) but the x-axis is showing the dates as numbers, e.g. 23 - 24 - 25. I'd love to see the words Monday, Tuesday et al in there instead.

When setting up the chart I have Fields!Date.Value as the category group, at the moment grouped on `=day(Fields!Date.Value)`

Any suggestions on how to get 'Monday', 'Tuesday' etc to appear would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be able to help you.

```
=weekdayname(weekday(Fields!Date.Value))
```

That will return the written day of the week based on the date provided.

--EDIT--

Below is a proof of concept and also the syntax to use to convert string input to datetime to be used with this expression

```
=weekdayname(weekday(cdate("2-28-2015")))
```

Change the date to any date and it will spit out the written name of the day.

Comment: Thanks very much for the prompt response. Please bear with me, but to clarify: I will need to add =weekdayname(weekday(Fields!Date.Value)) in the horizontal axis properties. However, I don't understand where I need to add the second part - =weekdayname(weekday(cdate("2-28-2015"))) to convert the string input.

Comment: You dont need to add the second part I just edited my answer to show the proof of concept I used to test the expression. You may on the other hand have to use the cdate() portion and turn you expression into `=weekdayname(weekday(cdate(fields!date.value)))`... the cdate() will convert a string date to a datetime. Only necessary if fields!date.value is a string. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Thanks for clarifying for me. I added =weekdayname(weekday(Fields!Date.Value)) to the x-axis values and it has returned a text value but just one day appears, eg across the x-axis it now says Monday Monday Monday Monday instead of Monday Tuesday et al. Any idea why I've got this repetition of one day, rather than Mon - Fri? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure could be a caching issue. I created a dataset as follows `select '2-1-2015'
union 
select '2-2-2015'
union 
select '2-3-2015'` and used the following expression `=weekdayname(weekday(cdate(fields!ID.Value)))` and this returned sunday monday tuesday... I would check to see that you don't have a .rdl.data file in your solution folder in your workspace. This can and will affect the output of your report when the same parameters are used.

Comment: OK thanks, will run a deeper investigation this end. In the meantime, your comments above have been invaluable in helping my understanding so many thanks for taking the time to reply to my questions.

Comment: Not a problem. That is what this site is all about. Just a hint tho. accepting an answer that works lets other know at a glance that the answer itself was helpful for you and might work for them.